# Qt Declarative cross compiling for STM32 giving error on Qt Base 6.3.0

Tags: c++, qt, arm, qt6, qtdeclarative

**Hey!
I have successfully cross-compiled Qt6 (6.3.0) base module for the STM32. I then tried adding QtShader module via qt-configure-module and it worked! However, when I am trying to add Qt Declarative the same way (using qt-configure-module), I am getting error on cmake build command. What am I doing wrong?**

```
*/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/10.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5037:29: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘QList<std::pair<QQmlJS::SourceLocation, QQmlJS::Dom::DomItem> >::iterator’ changed in GCC 7.1
 5037 |  std::__stable_sort_adaptive(__first, __last, __buf.begin(),
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 5038 |         _DistanceType(__buf.size()), __comp);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[2563/2573] Linking CXX executable bin/qml

FAILED: bin/qml 
: && /home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot -fPIC -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf     -Wl,--enable-new-dtags tools/qml/CMakeFiles/qml.dir/qml_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o tools/qml/CMakeFiles/qml.dir/main.cpp.o tools/qml/CMakeFiles/qml.dir/.rcc/qrc_qml.cpp.o tools/qml/CMakeFiles/qml.dir/qml_qmltyperegistrations.cpp.o tools/qml/CMakeFiles/qml.dir/.rcc/qrc_qmake_QmlRuntime_Config.cpp.o -o bin/qml  -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/qt-cross/qtdeclarative-everywhere-src-6.3.0/lib:/usr/local/qt6/lib:  lib/libQt6Qml.so.6.3.0  /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Network.so.6.3.0  /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Widgets.so.6.3.0  /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0  /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLX.so  /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libOpenGL.so  /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.3.0  -pthread  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/user/qt6-stm/lib && :
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libdl.so.2, needed by /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Network.so.6.3.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Network.so.6.3.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libexpat.so.1, needed by /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libuuid.so.1, needed by /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_type@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_new_method_call@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_get_stringnumber'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_allow_interactive_authorization@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_member@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_error_init@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_close_container@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get_private@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_get_completed@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_sender@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `compress2'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_threads_init_default@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_free'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_set_watch_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng16.so.16: undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_add_filter@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_ParseBuffer'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_ref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_free_data_slot@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_disconnect@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_init_append@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_no_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `deflate'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_error_name@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_set_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_ref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_get_is_connected@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_init@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `compress'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_set_new_connection_function@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_get_is_authenticated@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_config'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_enabled@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_signature@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_open_private@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_steal_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_interface@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `uuid_copy@UUID_1.0'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLX.so: undefined reference to `dlopen@GLIBC_2.4'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `uuid_parse@UUID_1.0'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_get_address@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_shutdown@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `crc32'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_new@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_free@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_handle@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_allocate_data_slot@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_dispatch@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_add_match@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_append_basic@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_fixed_array@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_recurse@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_handle@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_get_is_connected@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_flags@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_basic@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLX.so: undefined reference to `dlclose@GLIBC_2.4'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `dladdr@GLIBC_2.4'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Network.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_get_stringtable_entries'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_error_name@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_listen@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_server_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_destination@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_no_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_unix_fd@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send_with_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_get_interval@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_GetBuffer'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `XML_SetDoctypeDeclHandler'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_auto_start@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng16.so.16: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_watch_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/stm-sdk/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse@UUID_1.0'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_element_type@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_reply_serial@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_open_container@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_next@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_allow_interactive_authorization@LIBDBUS_1_3'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6Network.so.6.3.0: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/user/stm32/gcc-linaro-10.2.1-2021.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/qt6-stm/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_path@LIBDBUS_1_3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[2566/2573] Building CXX object src/qmldom/CMakeFiles/QmlDomPrivate.dir/qqmldomtop.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.*
```

Comment: Are you using the right compiler in the first place? `arm-linux-gnueabihf` triplet suggests the platform is some ARM running Linux. STM32 (from what I remember them at least) are bare-metal microcontrollers, so the compiler triplet matching them is sth like `arm-none-eabi` or similar.

Comment: Yes the compiler is right since the processor in the stm32 (it is a custom built) is armv7 based. I have project cross compiled using arm-linux-gnueabihf compiler for qt5 in the past too